# Using Fourier series of $x^2$ to evaluate Fourier series of $x^3+\pi^2 x$

Tags: integration, fourier-series

> Let $f,g$ be functions such that $f(x)=x^2 \ , \ g(x)=x^3+\pi^2 x$.
>
> Use Fourier series of $f$ to evaluate Fourier series of $g$. Domain is $[-\pi,\pi]$.

**My try:**

The Fourier series of $f(x)$ is $\displaystyle f(x)\sim \frac {\pi^2}{3}+4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\cos(nx)$.

Define $\displaystyle h(x)=f(x)+\frac{\pi^2}{3}$. $h(x)$ is piecewise continuous, hence we can integrate term by term.

We get $$\int\limits_{0}^{x}h(t)\text{d}t=\int\limits_{0}^{x}\left(x^2+\frac{\pi^2}{3}\right)\text{d}t=\frac{x^3+\pi^2x}{3}=\frac{g(x)}{3}=\frac{2\pi^2}{3}x+4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\cos(nx) \\ \therefore g(x)=2\pi^2 x+12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}\sin(nx)$$
My problem is that I don't get Fourier series. How should I tackle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $$f(x)=x^2=\frac{a_0}2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,\cos(nx)$$
the Fourier series of $f$ on $[-\pi,\,\pi]$. As $f$ is even, we only have cosines. The derivative of $f$ is
$$f'(x)=2x=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n\sin(nx)\tag{1}$$
and the antiderivative of $f$ is
$$\int_0^xf(y)\mathrm dy=\frac{x^3}3=\frac{a_0}2x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}n\sin(nx).\tag{2}$$
Using (1) in (2) we get
$$\int_0^xf(y)\mathrm dy=\frac{x^3}3=-\frac{a_0}4\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n\sin(nx)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}n\sin(nx).\tag{3}$$
Let us use (1) and (3) to express
$$g(x)=x^3+\pi^2x=3\int_0^xf(y)\mathrm dy+\frac{\pi^2}2f'(x)=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(3\frac{a_n}n-\frac{\pi^2}2na_n-\frac{3a_0}4na_n\right)\sin(nx).$$
The Fourier coefficients of $g$, such that $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin(nx)$ are therefore $$b_n=\left(\frac{3}n-n\frac{2\pi^2+3a_0}4\right)a_n.$$

Comment: What about $a_0=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$ in Fourier series of $x^2$?

Comment: You are right. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer is very helpful.

Comment: @Tom-Tom can you tell me why there is minus in here $ -\frac{\pi^2}2f'(x)$ thanks.

Comment: @lyme. That was a typo (fixed). All the rest is correct.